# kumuluzee: no main manifest

Tags: gradle, jakarta-ee, microprofile, kumuluzee

This is my `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id: 'java'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.kumuluz.ee:kumuluzee-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.kumuluz.ee:kumuluzee-servlet-jetty:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.kumuluz.ee:kumuluzee-microProfile-1.2:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.kumuluz.ee:kumuluzee-jpa-hibernate:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.kumuluz.ee:kumuluzee-bean-validation-hibernate-validator:3.1.0'
}
```

I run `gradle build` succesfully, but:

[image]

As you can see I'm getting an:

> no main manifest attribute, in build/libs/frontoffice.jar

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

By default, no manifest is generated by the `jar` task. Add this in your `build.gradle` :

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            'Main-Class': 'package.of.YourMainClass'
        )
    }
}
```